# Blog Post doesn't show images, bold text, or other attributes only the raw code... Django/Ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, blogs

I've followed a tutorial on implementing a ckeditor RichTextUploadingField() to my blog so I can have more functionality and better looking post/blogs.

Everything seems to be working but when I go to see the actual post after adding the picture and some words. I get a raw output with all my text...

Here is my output on my blog

```
<p><span style="color:#1a1a1a"><span style="background-color:#ffffff">First of all, I have assumed that you have seen countless rubbish articles, and still can&#39;t understand classes and objects, but at least know that there are two things like classes and objects.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="color:#1a1a1a"><span style="background-color:#ffffff">Since you don&#39;t have programming experience, you can&#39;t understand Python&#39;s &#39;classes and objects&#39; by analogy from the programming language you&#39;ve learned.&nbsp;Let&#39;s use the example of life to build a house.</span></span></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="color:#1a1a1a"><span style="background-color:#ffffff"><img alt="" src="/media/upload/2019/11/08/01.png" style="height:268px; width:400px" /></span></span></p>
```

Not sure why it doesn't look like the output I get before I post the article while I'm editing and creating it.

---

MODELS.PY

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} --> {self.author}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

POST_DETAIL.HTML

```
{% extends "portfolio_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <article class="media content-section">
                        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="article-metadata">
                                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:'F d, Y' }}</small>
                                {% if object.author == user %}
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update Post</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete Post</a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

POST_FORM.HTML

```
{% extends "portfolio_app/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="container col-md-6">
            <div class="content-section">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom md-4">Blog Post</legend>
                            {{ form.media }}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Am I missing something..? Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use |safe filter.

```
<h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title|safe }}</h2>
<p class="article-content">{{ object.content|safe }}</p>
```

Comment: I think this worked... but I'm not sure what I did I'm stuck in a loop when I try "python manage.py runserver" It keeps saying that C:\Users\****\settings.py changed, reloading... it reloads and tries to start but keeps getting stuck at file "changed", once I save it, I get the same error message about a different file.

Comment: BTW, it worked, but I don't understand why. What is '|safe'? Also I'm still stuck in a loop at "python manage.py runserver". But the site is working....? It loads, the file it's complaining about now is '0005_remove_post_descriptions.py'

Comment: i think your file `'0005_remove_post_descriptions.py' `  is  from migrations folder

Comment: Either way thank you so much! I'll research into what safe is, I'm sure it's simple I'm just starting out.